# How can i show incoming notification APNS message at specific row in tableview in iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uitableview, apple-push-notifications

How can i get `notification`text coming from `APNS`  to my `UITableView`? 
I am using `.xib` in objective-c. I want text coming from `APNS` notification to my `UITableView`

I would like to use arrays in this.

**I want Demo Code if possible.**

Answer (score 0):

Try below to insert text at specific place in tableview..

```
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
   [self.tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```